# I don't know how to do

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is my error

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Characters\ThirdPersonCharacter\Scripts\AICharacterControl.cs(7,31): 
error CS0118:'NavMeshAgent' is a namespace but is used like a type
```

This is my code I can't fix that :(

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;


namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.NavMeshAgent
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (NavMeshAgent))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (ThirdPersonCharacter))]
    public class AICharacterControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public NavMeshAgent agent { get; private set; } 
        public ThirdPersonCharacter character { get; private set; } 
        public Transform target; 

       
        private void Start()
        {
            
            agent = GetComponentInChildren<NavMeshAgent>();
            character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();

            agent.updateRotation = false;
            agent.updatePosition = true;
        }


       
        private void Update()
        {
            if (target != null)
            {
                agent.SetDestination(target.position);

                
                
                
                character.Move(agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
            }
            else
            {
                
                character.Move(Vector3.zero, false, false);
            }

        }


        public void SetTarget(Transform target)
        {
            this.target = target;
        }
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: The error means exactly what it says.  `NavMeshAgent` is not a type.  What do you expect `typeof(NavMeshAgent)` to do and why?  What do you expect `public NavMeshAgent agent { get; private set; }` to be and why?  Etc.

Comment: @David, the official documentation has this line as well: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-destination.html

Comment: You have defined your namespace to be "UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.NavMeshAgent" Note the name of its innermost (right-most) component. Now read the error message again. Question to you: Do you really need to specify one of the namespaces in your project "Something.Something.NavMeshAgent"? Can't you define a different namespace for your project classes?

Comment: The "standard assets" were basically retired a long time ago. So depending in which unity version youre using and there which navmesh etc. your cause could be the assets too old for your unity version or you just need to make a couple of updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the names of existing types as namespaces.  You have a custom namespace here:

```
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.NavMeshAgent
```

So anything *within* that namespace (or in code which references the enclosing namespace) which refers to `NavMeshAgent` will be referring to the *namespace*.  *Not* to the [type in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.html).

Rename your namespace.  For example:

```
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.MyNavMeshAgent
```

(Or something more contextually meaningful.)

Basically the lesson here is that names matter.  The names of your namespaces, types, variables, etc. should be clear and unambiguous to both you and to the compiler.

---

And, of course, to reference that type directly you'll need a `using` directive:

```
using UnityEngine.AI;
```